# When Tailwindcss has preflight set to false, the borders may become ineffective

Tags: tailwind-css

The border styles have no effect at all, how can this be resolved?

```
<div class="border border-indigo-600">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because preflights [sets](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#border-styles-are-reset-globally) `border-style` to be `solid`. By disabling preflights this CSS property is no longer valid and you need to specify [border-style](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-style) on your own

```html
<div class="border border-indigo-600 border-solid">
```